# Integrate $\int\frac{\cos^2(x)-x^2\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I had to integrate the following integral:

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\cos^2(x)-x^2\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2}dx
\end{equation}

but I can't find a suitable substitution to find a solution. Nothing I try works out and only seems to make it more complicated. Does anyone have an idea as to how to solve this?

I also tried to get help from WolframAlpha but it just says that there is no step-by-step solution available.

The sollution by wolfram alpha is:
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\cos^2(x)-x^2\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2}dx = \frac{x\cos(x)}{x+\cos(x)} + c
\end{equation}

Comment: But what is the solution by WolframAlpha?

Comment: I've included the solution by WolframAlpha in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\cos^2 x-x^2\sin x }{(x+\cos x)^2}dx
\end{equation}

Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^2\cos^2 x$

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\cos^2 x-x^2\sin x }{(x+\cos x)^2}dx
=\int\frac{\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}}{(\dfrac{1}{\cos x}+\dfrac{1}{x})^2}dx
=\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\cos x}+\dfrac{1}{x}} + C
=\frac{x\cos x}{x + \cos x} + C
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

When you see an integral like that, although you quickly find $u=x+\cos x$ won't work, you can't help but think there'll be a nice antiderivative of the form $\frac{f}{x+\cos x}$. So now, we want to solve $$\cos^2x-x^2\sin x=(x+\cos x)f^\prime-(1-\sin x)f.$$Can we write the left-hand side as a linear combination of $x+\cos x,\,1-\sin x$? After a little experimenting, yes: it's $$x\cos x-x^2\sin x+\cos^2x-x\cos x\sin x-x\cos x+x\cos x\sin x\\=(x+\cos x)(\cos x-x\sin x)-x\cos x(1-\sin x),$$implying the choice $f=x\cos x,\,f^\prime=\cos x-x\sin x$, which happily are consistent.

Comment: What you are indeed doing is applying the *quotient rule* in reverse. Namely $$\left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' = \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2}$$ and is a nice little trick provided the conjuring up of the function $u(x)$ is not too difficult.

Comment: @omegadot This time I was, yes. The broader point was that integrands often give an easy hint about *some* ingredient of their antiderivative, in this case of a denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the derivative of $x + \cos(x)$ in the denominator is $1-\sin(x)$ . We can try to make this term appear in the numerator and then integrate by parts. We have
$$ \frac{\cos^2(x)-x^2\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2} = \frac{\cos^2(x) - x^2 + x^2(1-\sin(x))}{(x+\cos(x))^2} = \frac{\cos(x) - x}{x+\cos(x)} + x^2 \frac{1-\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2} \, ,$$
so
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\cos^2(x)-x^2\sin(x)}{(x+\cos(x))^2} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{\cos(x) - x}{x+\cos(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x - \frac{x^2}{x+\cos(x)} +   \int \, \frac{2 x}{x+\cos(x)}\mathrm{d} x \\
&= x - \frac{x^2}{x+\cos(x)} = \frac{x \cos(x)}{x+\cos(x)}
\end{align}
as desired.